# For what real numbers $x > y > 0$ does the series converge

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Trying to find real numbers $x > y > 0 $ such that

$$\sum _{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{x^n - y^n} $$
converges.

Been solving for radius of convergence for power series based on one variable, $x$, but this is the first I've seen with two. Tips are appreciated, thank you

Comment: When you say you're trying to find real numbers, do you mean you want to find an *example* of real numbers for which the series converges, or do you mean you want to describe the entire *set* of (pairs of) real numbers for which the series converges?

Comment: If you want to find all such pairs $(x,y)$ the Ratio Test is your friend. Limit Comparison with a geometric is good too.

Comment: All pairs, thanks I'll give them a shot!

Comment: @AndréNicolas Would you mind elaborating a little bit on using the ratio test? After getting to $\frac{x^n - y^n}{x^{n+1} - y^{n+1}}$, I can't see where to continue. I need L to be < 1, but what's the next step?

Comment: We look at $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{x^n-y^n}{x^{n+1}-y^{n+1}}$. Divide top and bottom by $x^{n+1}$. Argue that the limit as $n\to\infty$ is $\frac{1}{x}$. We are OK if this is less than $1$ if $x\gt 1$, and $\gt 1$ if $x\lt 1$. So convergence if $x\gt 1$, divergence if $x\lt 1$. At $x=1$ terms don't have limit $0$ so divergence.

Comment: With Limit Comparison things are about the same, somewhat shorter to type since we are dividing $\frac{1}{x^n-y^n}$ by $\frac{1}{x^n}$. As an aside, next time please indicate what you have tried, so that the question will not be closed.